# Laravel: Create HasMany Relationship Based On Condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to display reproductions based on Gender Condition

Reproduction Table:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('father_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('mother_id');
...
```

I need to retrieve reproductions according to the gender

User.php

```
public function reproductions(){
    if($this->gender == 'm'){
        return $this->hasMany(Reproduction::class, 'father_id');
    }else{
        return $this->hasMany(Reproduction::class, 'mother_id');
    }
}
```

Reproduction Table:

```
id    father_id    mother_id

1         1            2

2         1            3

3         1            4
```

When I retrieve reproduction for User with id 1, it needed to display 3 reproductions but it returns null collection

```
$firstUser = User::find(1); // User Id with 1 has gender m

dd($firstUser->reproductions->count()); // Should return 3 but returns null collection
```

Comment: Why dont you create a piviot table between gender_user. From that point it does not matter what the id is. You can always filter and do a cout after that. Saves you from creating tow different relationship and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create two different relationships.

```
public function maleReproductions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Reproduction::class, 'father_id');
}
```

---

```
public function feMaleReproductions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Reproduction::class, 'mother_id');
}
```

now based on `$user` you can attach relationship.

```
$productions = [];
$user = User::where('id',1)->first();
if($user->gender == 'm'){
    $productions = $user->maleProductions;
} else {
    $productions = $user->feMaleProductions;
}
```

for collection of users, attach both relationship. and access specific based on condition.

```
$users = User::with('maleReproductions', 'femaleReproductions')->get();

foreach($users as $user){
    if($user->gender == 'm'){
       $productions = $user->maleProductions;
    } else {
       $productions = $user->feMaleProductions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. For the collection I did, `User::with('maleReproductions', 'femaleReproductions');` for eagar loading

Comment: and you access specific relationship in loop based on single collection item, right? would you mind edit my answer or give me code so I can edit it at my own.

Comment: Yes, same as you added the condition.