# Laravel Load Relation With Condition On Model

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm attempting to eager load a user's notifications with a relation that depends on a value of notification model:

```
$notifications = $user->notifications()
    ->with([
        'notifiable' => function ($query) {
            // Only load notifiable relation if notification 'notifiable_type' equals...
        },
        'notifiable.group:id,title' => function ($query) {
            // Only load notifiable.group:id,title relation if notification 'notifiable_type' equals... 
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

The issue is the `$query` within the closures are querying on the `notifiable` relation rather than the notification model itself... I'm obviously missing something very trivial. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Create HasMany Relationship Based On Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826319/laravel-create-hasmany-relationship-based-on-condition)

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi no it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`Lazy Eager Loading`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

```
$notifications = $user->notifications;

$notifications->each(function ($item) {
    if ($item->notifiable_type == 'value-one') {
        $item->load('notifiable');
    }

    if ($item->notifiable_type == 'value-two') {
        $item->load('notifiable.group:id,title');
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice! I did something similar within the API Resource for the Notification model by checking `$this->notifiable_type` and lazy loading, however i would much prefer keeping that logic out the API Resource. Cant believe I didn't think of this!